# CaptainCasa framework: touchfieldnumeric component auto flush and layout

Tags: jsp, captaincasa

In the captaincasa framework i want to use the t:touchfieldnumeric component for a pin input scenario.

Is it possible to change the layout of the keys so that i have the numbers 0-9 and C/delete buttons below them and not to the side ?

Also is it possible to have auto-flush to the server when a certain number of characters are inputted ?

Comment: I added [captaincasa] tag. Please update all your previous questions to use this tag instead of [java]. You both also need to disclose in your user profile that you're working for "captaincasa framework", else all these posts might get marked as spam by the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at Layout:
The touch layout can be defined by yourself. It is a semicolon-separated definition of the virtual keyboard content. Please check the demo "Components > Touch Screen > Touch Keyboard Layouts" for details.

at Auto-Flush:
The content currently is flushed when pressing the OK button within the touch dialog. We like the idea to do this automatically on reaching a certain number of digits + will add this to the component. Should be part of next update (i.e. next Monday or interim update on your request).

Kind regards!

Comment: We just published the change with version 20231013_INT1 (interim version, available by Maven-repository). New attributes: MAXLENGTH and MAXLENGTHAUTOFLUSH. Would be great if you could test a bit - thanks!